# Nginx rewrite module (Catch-all)

Tags: nginx

I'm new to Nginx, how can I rewrite this mod_rewrite, so that will work in Nginx?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
```

I tried this, but it didn't work.

```
location / {

    (...)

    reqrite (.*) /index.php last;

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: is the `reqrite` a typo or is it what you are trying? It should be `rewrite`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
location / {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php last;
}
```

Comment: Still '500 Internal Server Error'. :-(

Comment: try with break.

Comment: when i try adding this it outputs my php source into the browser ! ...

Comment: @HaydenThring That's probably because you are not executing the PHP, you also will need to have it configured to actually execute the PHP.

Comment: It should be `last` instead of `break` to allow the php location to still redirect the code to the php (f)cgi.